# Using Capybara with Webkit to select an option from a Chosen Multiselector

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, capybara

I have a multiselector that uses the Chosen plugin as shown below:

```
<%= select_tag :provinces,
options_for_select(DataHelper::all_provinces_captions.zip(DataHelper::all_provinces_ids)),
{:multiple => true, class: 'chosen-select chzn-select', 
:data => {:placeholder => 'Filter Provinces/States'}, 
:style => "width: 100%; height: 100px;"}%>
```

Here are the relevant DataHelper selection arrays:

```
def self.all_provinces_captions
    usa_provinces_with_caption.map { |x| x.first } + canada_provinces_with_caption.map { |x| x.first }
end
def self.all_provinces_ids
    usa_provinces_with_caption.map { |x| (Province.find_by name: x.first).id} + canada_provinces_with_caption.map { |x| (Province.find_by name: x.first).id }
end
def self.usa_provinces_with_caption
        [["Alabama", "alabama"], ["Alaska", "alaska"], ["Arizona", "arizona"], ["Arkansas", "arkansas"], ["California", "california"], ["Colorado", "colorado"], ["Connecticut", "connecticut"], ["Delaware", "delaware"], ["District Of Columbia", "district of columbia"], ["Florida", "florida"], ["Georgia", "georgia"], ["Hawaii", "hawaii"], ["Idaho", "idaho"], ["Illinois", "illinois"], ["Indiana", "indiana"], ["Iowa", "iowa"], ["Kansas", "kansas"], ["Kentucky", "kentucky"], ["Louisiana", "louisiana"], ["Maine", "maine"], ["Maryland", "maryland"], ["Massachusetts", "massachusetts"], ["Michigan", "michigan"], ["Minnesota", "minnesota"], ["Mississippi", "mississippi"], ["Missouri", "missouri"], ["Montana", "montana"], ["Nebraska", "nebraska"], ["Nevada", "nevada"], ["New Hampshire", "new hampshire"], ["New Jersey", "new jersey"], ["New Mexico", "new mexico"], ["New York", "new york"], ["North Carolina", "north carolina"], ["North Dakota", "north dakota"], ["Ohio", "ohio"], ["Oklahoma", "oklahoma"], ["Oregon", "oregon"], ["Pennsylvania", "pennsylvania"], ["Rhode Island", "rhode island"], ["South Carolina", "south carolina"], ["South Dakota", "south dakota"], ["Tennessee", "tennessee"], ["Texas", "texas"], ["Utah", "utah"], ["Vermont", "vermont"], ["Virginia", "virginia"], ["Washington", "washington"], ["West Virginia", "west virginia"], ["Wisconsin", "wisconsin"], ["Wyoming", "wyoming"]]
end
def self.canada_provinces_with_caption
        [["Alberta", "alberta"], ["British Columbia", "british columbia"], ["Manitoba", "manitoba"], ["New Brunswick", "new brunswick"], ["Newfoundland", "newfoundland"], ["Northwest Territories", "northwest territories"], ["Nova Scotia", "nova scotia"], ["Nunavut", "nunavut"], ["Ontario", "ontario"], ["Prince Edward Island", "prince edward island"], ["Quebec", "quebec"], ["Saskatchewan", "saskatchewan"], ["Yukon", "yukon"]]
end
```

How do I select an option from this chosen selector in a Capybara integration test on the Ruby on Rails framework? I have tried the conventional selector method, and that hasn't work, as well as the Capybara method for filling out textboxes - and that hasn't worked for me either.

The HTML that the Chosen plugin creates from the ERB:

```
<select name="provinces[]" id="provinces" multiple="multiple" class="chosen-select chzn-select" data-placeholder="Filter Provinces/States" style="width: 100%; height: 100px; display: none;" data-original-title="" title="">
<option value="420860745" data-original-title="" title="">Alabama</option>
<option value="121193182" data-original-title="" title="">Alaska</option>
<option value="614988510" data-original-title="" title="">Arizona</option>
<option value="1011954550" data-original-title="" title="">Arkansas</option>
<option value="51576297" data-original-title="" title="">California</option>
<option value="911438059" data-original-title="" title="">Colorado</option>
<option value="29252426" data-original-title="" title="">Connecticut</option>
<option value="742732841" data-original-title="" title="">Delaware</option>
<option value="335579331" data-original-title="" title="">District Of Columbia</option>
<option value="743108299" data-original-title="" title="">Florida</option>
<option value="302180340" data-original-title="" title="">Georgia</option>
<option value="245056076" data-original-title="" title="">Hawaii</option>
<option value="528006663" data-original-title="" title="">Idaho</option>
<option value="684024883" data-original-title="" title="">Illinois</option>
<option value="335439766" data-original-title="" title="">Indiana</option>
<option value="1042961784" data-original-title="" title="">Iowa</option>
<option value="252128415" data-original-title="" title="">Kansas</option>
<option value="908162754" data-original-title="" title="">Kentucky</option>
<option value="884793715" data-original-title="" title="">Louisiana</option>
<option value="633010136" data-original-title="" title="">Maine</option>
<option value="945883618" data-original-title="" title="">Maryland</option>
<option value="436583221" data-original-title="" title="">Massachusetts</option>
<option value="177885659" data-original-title="" title="">Michigan</option>
<option value="935527986" data-original-title="" title="">Minnesota</option>
<option value="312520863" data-original-title="" title="">Mississippi</option>
<option value="457050403" data-original-title="" title="">Missouri</option>
<option value="70125510" data-original-title="" title="">Montana</option>
<option value="376616596" data-original-title="" title="">Nebraska</option>
<option value="780899985" data-original-title="" title="">Nevada</option>
<option value="689473862" data-original-title="" title="">New Hampshire</option>
<option value="389522924" data-original-title="" title="">New Jersey</option>
<option value="380649796" data-original-title="" title="">New Mexico</option>
<option value="125610863" data-original-title="" title="">New York</option>
<option value="255810450" data-original-title="" title="">North Carolina</option>
<option value="428342329" data-original-title="" title="">North Dakota</option>
<option value="771165943" data-original-title="" title="">Ohio</option>
<option value="700707689" data-original-title="" title="">Oklahoma</option>
<option value="41766435" data-original-title="" title="">Oregon</option>
<option value="943799741" data-original-title="" title="">Pennsylvania</option>
<option value="764139748" data-original-title="" title="">Rhode Island</option>
<option value="720371240" data-original-title="" title="">South Carolina</option>
<option value="703335251" data-original-title="" title="">South Dakota</option>
<option value="562518602" data-original-title="" title="">Tennessee</option>
<option value="696317355" data-original-title="" title="">Texas</option>
<option value="299039922" data-original-title="" title="">Utah</option>
<option value="791562217" data-original-title="" title="">Vermont</option>
<option value="908498527" data-original-title="" title="">Virginia</option>
<option value="303977536" data-original-title="" title="">Washington</option>
<option value="512750023" data-original-title="" title="">West Virginia</option>
<option value="647404661" data-original-title="" title="">Wisconsin</option>
<option value="621732077" data-original-title="" title="">Wyoming</option>
<option value="100803856" data-original-title="" title="">Alberta</option>
<option value="950914246" data-original-title="" title="">British Columbia</option>
<option value="796505466" data-original-title="" title="">Manitoba</option>
<option value="536137098" data-original-title="" title="">New Brunswick</option>
<option value="4906295" data-original-title="" title="">Newfoundland</option>
<option value="65026714" data-original-title="" title="">Northwest Territories</option>
<option value="784270339" data-original-title="" title="">Nova Scotia</option>
<option value="768475533" data-original-title="" title="">Nunavut</option>
<option value="602098473" data-original-title="" title="">Ontario</option>
<option value="668705057" data-original-title="" title="">Prince Edward Island</option>
<option value="185902858" data-original-title="" title="">Quebec</option>
<option value="318605132" data-original-title="" title="">Saskatchewan</option>
<option value="585906940" data-original-title="" title="">Yukon</option></select>
```

Followed by a second part:

```
<div class="chosen-container chosen-container-multi" style="width: 277px;" title="" id="provinces_chosen" data-original-title="">
  <ul class="chosen-choices" data-original-title="" title="">
    <li class="search-field" data-original-title="" title="">
      <input type="text" value="Filter Provinces/States" class="default" autocomplete="off" style="width: 155px;" data-original-title="" title="">
      </li>
   </ul>
 <div class="chosen-drop" data-original-title="" title="">
   <ul class="chosen-results" data-original-title="" title="">
     <li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="0">Alabama</li>
     <li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="1">Alaska</li>
     <li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="2">Arizona</li>
     <li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="3">Arkansas</li>
     <li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="4">California</li>
     <li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="5">Colorado</li>
     <li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="6">Connecticut</li>
     <li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="7">Delaware</li>
     <li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="8">District Of Columbia</li>
     <li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="9">Florida</li>
     <li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="10">Georgia</li>
     <li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="11">Hawaii</li>
     <li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="12">Idaho</li>
     <li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="13">Illinois</li>
     <li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="14">Indiana</li>
     <li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="15">Iowa</li>
     <li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="16">Kansas</li>
     <li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="17">Kentucky</li>
     <li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="18">Louisiana</li>
     <li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="19">Maine</li>
     <li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="20">Maryland</li>
     <li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="21">Massachusetts</li>   
     <li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="22">Michigan</li>
     <li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="23">Minnesota</li><li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="24">Mississippi</li>
     <li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="25">Missouri</li>
     <li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="26">Montana</li>
     <li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="27">Nebraska</li>
     <li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="28">Nevada</li>
     <li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="29">New Hampshire</li>
     <li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="30">New Jersey</li>
     <li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="31">New Mexico</li>
     <li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="32">New York</li>
     <li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="33">North Carolina</li>
     <li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="34">North Dakota</li>
     <li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="35">Ohio</li>
     <li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="36">Oklahoma</li>
     <li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="37">Oregon</li>
     <li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="38">Pennsylvania</li>
     <li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="39">Rhode Island</li>
     <li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="40">South Carolina</li>
     <li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="41">South Dakota</li>
     <li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="42">Tennessee</li>
     <li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="43">Texas</li>
     <li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="44">Utah</li>
     <li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="45">Vermont</li>
     <li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="46">Virginia</li>
     <li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="47">Washington</li>
     <li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="48">West Virginia</li><li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="49">Wisconsin</li>
     <li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="50">Wyoming</li>
     <li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="51">Alberta</li>
     <li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="52">British Columbia</li>
     <li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="53">Manitoba</li>
     <li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="54">New Brunswick</li>
     <li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="55">Newfoundland</li>
     <li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="56">Northwest Territories</li>
     <li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="57">Nova Scotia</li>
     <li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="58">Nunavut</li>
     <li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="59">Ontario</li>
     <li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="60">Prince Edward Island</li>
     <li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="61">Quebec</li>
     <li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="62">Saskatchewan</li>
     <li class="active-result" data-option-array-index="63">Yukon</li>
   </ul>
 </div>
```

Hope the above info helps!

Comment: Capybaras `select` only works with actual select boxes, which I assume the `Chosen` widget replaces with other HTML elements (ul/li elements, etc). Please add the actual HTML that appears on the page (rather than the erb) after the Chosen plugin has manipulated it.

Comment: @TomWalpole alright, I have edited the question accordingly, hope it helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use a JS driven widget you need to have Capybara do what a user would have to do.  In this case that is click on the container, which makes the widget display the dropdown, and then click on the element you want from the dropdown options.  For your HTML that would be something like

```
find('#provinces_chosen .chosen-choices').click
find('.chosen-results .active-result', text: 'Alabama').click
```

The first line may actually need to be

```
find('#provinces_chosen .chosen-choices .search-field').click
```

since it's a multi-select to keep working for you second and third choices - easy enough to test.

Comment: @KeyanRhm - Yeah the second would probably only be required if you select a few items that end up covering the middle of the .chosen-choices box -- If the second works it's probably a little safer, but whichever works for you.